# AC current terminals

Tags: current, ac, terminal

I have a question that has really been eating up my mind since High School on Ac current and voltages,
If its really true and i know it is that Ac current terminals keep alternating at a rate of 50 Hz per sec as in the case of my country.
 Why do we have one constant positive terminal that keeps lighting up a tester and can even  shock you?

Comment: heard of *persistence of vision*?

Comment: no i haven't. what about it?

Comment: "Hz per sec" is non-sensical in this context.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we have one constant positive terminal that keeps lighting up a tester

AC mains have a 'live' terminal not a positive terminal. And the voltage at live terminal varies sinusoidally in between  -ve voltages and +ve voltages with respect to the neutral line at a rate of 50Hz. So the intensity of light also changes with this voltage variation. But because of [persistence of vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision), human eye can not detect this variation. Eye will perceive it as a constant intensity light (whose intensity will be about average of the original varying value).

*In short, the inability of human eye to detect 50Hz variation creates an illusion of constant light.*

> Why no electric shock?

Tester uses a neon lamp inside it [\$^{\mathrm{[source]}}\$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_light#One-contact_neon_test_lights).  The neon lamp takes very little current to light, and thus can use the user's body capacitance to earth ground to complete the circuit. This small current won't be a problem for human body.

*In short, the high resistance offered by tester limits the current through it reducing the chance of electric shock.*

Comment: so what's really the difference between a live and a positive terminal?

Comment: live terminal is for mains. A live terminal in mains provides the varying ac voltage with respect to neutral line. A positive terminal in DC source provides a constant potential higher than the negative terminal of the source.